# android onServiceDisconnected() is not called even when service is killed

Tags: android, android-service

I wrote an app including a service with the below attribute set in the manifest file:

```
(android:process=":remote)
```

When I call bindService(), it establishes the connection and onServiceConnected() gets invoked.

However, when I call killBackgroundProcesses() to kill the service process, onServiceDisconnected() never gets invoked.

The documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html#onServiceDisconnected(android.content.ComponentName)  says that onServiceDisconnected() is called whenever the process hosting the service has crashed or been killed. Any idea why it's not being invoked in the above case?

Comment: Don't use that.  It kills the process immediately so it's not going to call any of the callbacks because the service dies.  Call `stopService()` instead.  If the service is only creaked by `bindService()` (i.e., you never call `startService()`), then you don't need to worry about stopping it.

Comment: I see. I actually don't want to call stopService() since that's the standard behavior and onServiceDisconnected() will be called. What I'm trying to do is to simulate the scenario in which service gets killed by OS which may due to several reasons or it crashes for some other reason, then how the client knows about it and try to reconnect to the service.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the DeathRecipient callback as part of IBinder.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/IBinder.html#linkToDeath(android.os.IBinder.DeathRecipient, int)